# Is there a way to view my active objects/files in Visual Studio Code similar to R Studio environment?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, rstudio

I recently started switching from R Studio to Visual Studio Code (I have a Mac). I am missing the R Studio environment where I can see what objects, functions, and files are loaded in and their dimensions. Is there anything similar in VS Code?

I know I can view my objects with `View` and use `ls` to see what is in the active environment, but it is not the same as the quick reference like R Studio has.

Comment: check out this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r, it ships with a sidebar that shows your variables. To install - go to Extensions (on the left side, looks like a square with 1 block escaping) and search for `R Extension for Visual Studio Code`. As an aside, I found `Spyder` to have a IDE very similar to RStudio.

Comment: Yes, what is called the "Environment" in RStudio is called the "Workspace" in VSCode. If you have the R extension installed that Donald linked to above, on the left-side of VSCode should be several buttons, like a search button, an extensions button, etc. One of them should be the R logo. Clicking on that should open up the Workspace pane to show which objects and functions are in the current environment.

Comment: Just to add to @coip, see [this](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Sidebar-user-interface#workspace-viewer)